# Cannot return value from main

Tags: c#

```
static string Main(string[] args)
{
    //IPAddress ipAddress = System.Net.IPAddress.Loopback;
    IPAddress ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.0.100");
    IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 1515);
    Socket sock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
    Connect(localEndPoint, sock);
    string packet;
    packet = Console.ReadLine();
    packet += "<EOF>";
    Send(sock, packet);
    Receive(sock);
    return packet;
    //connectDone.WaitOne();
}
```

This is me Client mail section, when i try to return my string from my server respond (packet variable) the compiler error is `Program '...\clie.exe' does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point`

Answer (score 12):

Quoted from this [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228506%28v=vs.90%29.aspx):

> Main can only return int or void, and has an optional string array argument to represent command-line parameters:

The return value of `main()` is the exit status of the application. Thus it must be an `int`, or `void`. If your goal is to print the final result, you need to use `Console.WriteLine()`.

Further reading: [Main() Return Values](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0fwzzxz2%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Comment: +1 since you provided a link (or two), and deleting my own answer which, like all other here, states exactly the same thing :-)

Comment: I forgot to mention that my server respond is allays a string number so i can change the main return type to int and use in.parse, but after the server return the respond how can i take this respond (as i mention before i am open the client exe file using another program)

Answer (score 2):

In C#, a main method is required to be a **void** or **int**

You modified the main to return a string, so that method is just like any other method in a class... and your program is without a real main method

Check [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0fwzzxz2%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) for further informations.

Answer (score 1):

The only choices are `static void Main(string[] args)` and `static int (string[] args)` Returning a string is not option.

Comment: [This MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acy3edy3%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) states that "Main must be static and it should not be public".

Comment: Thank you @xbonez Someone got java in my answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

Console applications can return an optional integer error level value, using the syntax:

```
static int Main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

To return a string value however you must use console output or some other stream - file, etc - to transfer the data.  Console redirection works, so you can pipe the output of you console application into the input of the next application in the chain, or into a file for later use.

Try usuing the `Console.Write()` and `Console.WriteLine()` methods an capture the output to a file initially to check the format, then use piping to get it into the input of the program that needs to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Starting with C# 7.1, **Main** can also return `Task` or `Task <int>`

See [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/program-structure/main-command-line#overview).